# Pin version with go get

Tags: go, go-modules, go-get

I 'd like to pin the version of one package, so whenever I run

```
go get -u ./...
```

..this package would stay unchanged (but the rest refreshed normally).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [go modules](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules). It was specifically designed to handle precise version control.

In your package's `go.mod` you can pin any dependencies to a fixed version e.g.

```
module example.com/hello
go 1.12
require (
    golang.org/x/text v0.3.0 // indirect
    rsc.io/quote v1.5.2
    rsc.io/quote/v3 v3.0.0
    rsc.io/sampler v1.3.1 // indirect
)
```

You can update individual package versions e.g.:

```
go get rsc.io/quote/v3@master
```

Will pull the latest commit version (beyond even any semver tagged version).
You can also hand edit `go.mod` for extra precision.

P.S. you need go version 1.11 or later for go modules. go 1.13 has modules turned on by default. Earlier versions you have to explicitly enable it via the env var `GO111MODULE=ON`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm already using go-modules, the problem is that there are too many dependencies to update them one-by-one, that's why `go get -u ./...` would be useful for me. Is there an alternative way to do a general upgrade?

Comment: You can clone the repo you want to fix to a local directory. Then use the `replace` directive in `go.mod` - this will prevent go-build from using an internet version of the pkg - but use the local (fixed) copy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pin specific version for a particular Go package, then it can be done via [`replace` directive](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace). For example, the following `go.mod` config pins `golang.org/x/exp` to `v0.0.0-20230713183714-613f0c0eb8a1`, so `go get -u -d ./...` doesn't updated this package to newer version:

```
module github.com/myname/mymodule

replace golang.org/x/exp => golang.org/x/exp v0.0.0-20230713183714-613f0c0eb8a1

require (
  ...
  // This version is updated with go get -u -d ./..., but it is always
  // overridden by the version specified in the replace directive above
  golang.org/x/exp v0.0.0-20231006140011-7918f672742d
  ...
)
```